# Determining if three lines lie on a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

What's the general method to determine if there exists a plane that contains three given lines? Context: trying to work out if three "points" are collinear but in real projective space where "points" are lines through the origin and planes through the origin are "lines".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your lines all pass through a single point (which your context suggests they do: the origin), then you can determine whether or not they are coplanar by determining whether or not the direction vectors defining the line are linearly independent or not.

If you have three lines defined by the vector equations
\begin{align*}
\vec{x} &= \vec{a} + t\vec{v}_1 \\
\vec{x} &= \vec{a} + t\vec{v}_2 \\
\vec{x} &= \vec{a} + t\vec{v}_3,
\end{align*}
then form the matrix $M$ with three columns: $v_1, v_2, v_3$. Row reduce the matrix. If the result has pivots (leading $1$s) in all three columns, then the three lines are **not** coplanar. The converse is true too: if the three lines are not coplanar, any row-echelon form of $M$ will have three pivots.

Note: in a more general setting, where the lines do not intersect at a given point, looking at direction vectors alone is not sufficient! Two skew lines will not be contained in any plane, for example!